How to tag all text after a specific symbol in Spacy?
I am trying to tag a word using regex and patterns in spacy:
{'lower': {"regex": "^.*(word).*?"}}

What I'm trying to do now is to tag the whole text after there symbol '/', no matter the spaces. So if it finds this symbol in text it takes everything after it as well.
Example:

"This is word/ year" it should tag "word/ year"
"This is subword / year" it should tag "subword / year"

I cannot figure how to do it using spacy.
I tried playing with regex, but nothing seems to work.

Try: \b\w+\s*/\s*\w+\b. See https://regex101.com/r/T2P516/latest

You need to keep in mind that SpaCy operates on tokens and each token is a separate entity that a regex is applied on. So you cannot match two or three tokens with a regex using the approach you have. You probably need to write your own tokenizer, or modify the one you are using.
